# How to rotate a matrix 90 degrees without using any extra space?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Algorithm to rotate an image 90 degrees in place? (No extra memory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968397/algorithm-to-rotate-an-image-90-degrees-in-place-no-extra-memory)

By saying 90 degrees i mean to say if:

```
A = {1,2,3,
     4,5,6,
     7,8,9}
```

then after 90 degree rotation A becomes:

```
A = {7,4,1,
     8,5,2,
     9,6,3}
```

Comment: No, the matrix can even be rectangular.

Comment: What language are you using ?

Comment: Only square matrix can be rotated in-place. We would change the dimension of a rectangular matrix after rotating, from MxN to NxM, so we need to create a new matrix in that case.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

let `a` be an nxn array 0 based indexing

```
f = floor(n/2)
c = ceil(n/2)

for x = 0 to f - 1
  for y = 0 to c - 1
    temp = a[x,y]
    a[x,y] = a[y,n-1-x]
    a[y,n-1-x] = a[n-1-x,n-1-y]
    a[n-1-x,n-1-y] = a[n-1-y,x]
    a[n-1-y,x] = temp
```

**Edit** If you want to avoid using temp, this works  (it also rotates in the correct direction)  this time in python.

```
def rot2(a):
  n = len(a)
  c = (n+1) / 2
  f = n / 2
  for x in range(c):
    for y in range(f):
      a[x][y] = a[x][y] ^ a[n-1-y][x]
      a[n-1-y][x] = a[x][y] ^ a[n-1-y][x]
      a[x][y] = a[x][y] ^ a[n-1-y][x]

      a[n-1-y][x] = a[n-1-y][x] ^ a[n-1-x][n-1-y]
      a[n-1-x][n-1-y] = a[n-1-y][x] ^ a[n-1-x][n-1-y]
      a[n-1-y][x] = a[n-1-y][x] ^ a[n-1-x][n-1-y]

      a[n-1-x][n-1-y] = a[n-1-x][n-1-y]^a[y][n-1-x]
      a[y][n-1-x] = a[n-1-x][n-1-y]^a[y][n-1-x]
      a[n-1-x][n-1-y] = a[n-1-x][n-1-y]^a[y][n-1-x]
```

Note:  This only works for matrices of integers.

Comment: isn't using temp wrong..? aren't we using an extra space?

Comment: It is one location. It is as wrong as using x and y, f and c.  If your array has integers you could use the xor swap trick, but you would still need x and y and at least implicitly f and c

Comment: Usually when discussing algorithms constant space requirements are usually not considered "extra space". Extra space is usually a complete copy of the whole or parts of the datastructure.

Comment: also, I'm rotating in the wrong direction, I'll put an updated version soon.

Comment: in python we can swap two elements by just doing a,b = b,a

Comment: Pretty sure this is incorrect. Run the code.

Comment: I've implemented variations of your code in [Hack Fast Algos](https://github.com/cozylife/hackfastalgos/blob/master/lib/matrixrotate.php) to demonstrate how to rotate and flip a matrix in many ways.

Comment: @zallarak I ran the code and it works when N is even, though I haven't been able to decipher why it works >.<!

Comment: @deinst can you tell me what's the idea behind the first algorithm? Does it rely on some sort of symmetry?

Comment: Where is the (n+1)/2 and n/2 coming from?

Comment: @pdn They are half of n.  The reason that (n+1)/2 is there is that in the outer loop we need to work on the center row/column when n is odd.

Answer (score 106):

Transpose and interchange rows or columns (depends whether you want to rotate left or right).

e. g.

```
1) original matrix

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

2) transpose

1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9

3-a) change rows to rotate left

3 6 9
2 5 8
1 4 7

3-b) or change columns to rotate right

7 4 1
8 5 2
9 6 3
```

All these operations can be done without allocating memory.

Comment: This algorithm will touch each element twice. An interviewer might ask if it's possible to just touch the element once.

Comment: @Narek will it work for when the size of rows != size of cols??

Comment: @Narek hmm. that means there will be some fixed initial size for rows and cols always otherwise if rows = 3 and cols =2 then we can't rotate in place

Comment: For posterity: 'change rows' means 'flip row 0 with row n, row 1 with row n-1, etc'. Similar for columns.

Answer (score 11):

The algorithm is to rotate each "ring", working from the outermost to the innermost.

```
AAAAA
ABBBA
ABCBA
ABBBA
AAAAA
```

The algorithm would rotate all the A's first, then B's then C's. Rotating a ring requires moving 4 values at once.

The index i ranges from 0..ring-width-1, e.g. for A the width is 5.

```
  (i,0) -> temp
  (0, N-i-1) -> (i, 0)
  (N-i-1, N-1) -> (0, N-i-1)
  (N-1, i) -> (N-i-1, N-1)
  temp -> (N-1, i)
```

This is then repeated for each successive inner ring, offsetting the co-ordinates reducing the ring width by 2.

[Another answer has appeared with the code, so I'll not repeat that.]

Comment: If it's not a square NxN matrix, it's difficult to rotate each ring

Comment: @PeterLee, I dont think rotating a non-square matrix is even possible

Comment: @ChanderShivdasani, I agree with you. But if it's a square matrix, the ring rotation is a good idea.

Comment: @ChanderShivdasani: rotating a non-square matrix is possible.. You just need to store it in a square matrix with other values `NULL`

Answer (score 3):

See [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition) for in-place matrix transposition; also google for "in-place matrix transposition". It can be easily adapted to perform rotation by 90 degrees. To transpose square matrices, you just interchange `b[i][j]` with `b[j][i]` where `b[k][l]` is `a[n*k+l]`. On nonsquare matrices, it's considerably more difficult. "Without any extra space" is a rather strong requirement, maybe you meant O(1) space? (assuming integers are fixed size) Implementation in C++: [here](http://www.cheshirekow.com/wordpress/?p=384).

Answer (score 3):

Complete implementation in C using the method described by @Narek above

```
#include <stdio.h>

int n;
unsigned int arr[100][100];

void rotate() {

    int i,j,temp;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(j=i; j<n; j++) {
            if(i!=j) {
                arr[i][j]^=arr[j][i];
                arr[j][i]^=arr[i][j];
                arr[i][j]^=arr[j][i];
            }
        }
    }


    for(i=0; i<n/2; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++) {
            arr[j][i]^=arr[j][n-1-i];
            arr[j][n-1-i]^=arr[j][i];
            arr[j][i]^=arr[j][n-1-i];
        }
    }

}

void display(){

    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++) {
            printf("%d",arr[i][j]);}
            printf("%s","\n");
        }
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int i,j;

    printf("%s","Enter size of matrix:");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("%s","Enter matrix elements\n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++) {
            scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
        }
    }

    rotate();
    display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you supplement your code with comment at each for loop?

Comment: @MusséRedi just swapping with `XOR` operation `^`, nothing more specific. Firstly, swapping while transposing. Secondly, while changing columns.
My corrections towards the realisation: you should start `j` from `i + 1` and remove `if (i != j)` while transposing, you can also replace transformations with `std::swap`

Answer (score 1):

You need one temp variable, then it is just to jump elements around.

```
temp = A[0];
A[0] = A[6];
A[6] = A[8];
A[8] = A[2];
A[2] = temp;
temp = A[1];
A[1] = A[3];
A[3] = A[7];
A[7] = A[5];
A[5] = temp;
```

Comment: the size of array isn't fixed.. it can vary.. what about 64x64 array..? I just mentioned the array as an example.

Answer (score -1):

I came across the following implementation:

For square matrices:

```
for n = 0 to N - 2
    for m = n + 1 to N - 1
        swap A(n,m) with A(m,n)
```

For rectangular matrices:

```
for each length>1 cycle C of the permutation
    pick a starting address s in C
    let D = data at s
    let x = predecessor of s in the cycle
    while x ≠ s
        move data from x to successor of x
        let x = predecessor of x
    move data from D to successor of s
```

For more info, one can refer here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition

Comment: You described and linked to matrix transposition, but the OP asked for matrix rotation.