# Need help in understanding how the solution to rotate N*N matrice by 90 degree in place works

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to understand the solution to rotating an N*N array by 90 degree in place.
Here is the reference to the question that was asked earlier but is closed now - 
[link] [How to rotate a matrix 90 degrees without using any extra space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488691/how-to-rotate-a-matrix-90-degrees-without-using-any-extra-space)
The best voted answer looks pretty neat but i am not able to understand it enough can somebody pls explain these steps

Comment: [Here](http://imgur.com/vbc0bbd) is a gif I made that shows how elements are swapped during an in-place rotation. Maybe it will be of some use.

Comment: Nice gif! Note, @Sandy, that the corner is square if N is even (`N / 2 == (N + 1) / 2`).

Comment: thanks @Kevin :) Pavel i have started to understand this concept now - and i notice that in kevin's gif the whole program is trying to balance the first quadrant which triggers off like a chain reaction .. trying to place the onces whose position is taken up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is using the [XOR swap trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm) which is not needed in python since you can swap all four elements at once in a single expression:

```
def rot2(a):
    n = len(a)
    for x in range((n + 1) / 2):
        for y in range(n / 2):
            a[x][y], a[n-1-y][x], a[y][n-1-x], a[n-1-x][n-1-y] = (
                                                      a[y][n-1-x],
                                                      a[x][y], 
                                                      a[n-1-x][n-1-y],
                                                      a[n-1-y][x],
                                                 )
```

**N×N matrix, N = 3:**

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

`N / 2 = 1`, `(N + 1)/2 = 2`.

`x = [0, 2)` (0 or 1), `y = [0, 1)` (0).

Corner:

```
 1 2 | 3
_____|
 4 5   6
 7 8   9
```

Swaps: `1 ← 3 ← 7 ← 9 (← 1)`; `2 ← 6 ← 8 ← 4 (← 2)`

**5×5 matrix:**

```
a b c d e
f g h i j
k l m n o
p q r s t
u v w x y
```

`N / 2 = 2`, `(N + 1)/2 = 3`.

`x = [0, 3)` (0 or 1 or 2), `y = [0, 2)` (0 or 1).

Corner:

```
a b c | d e
f g h | i j
______|
k l m   n o
p q r   s t
u v w   x y
```

Swaps:

```
a ← e ← y ← u
f ← d ← t ← v
b ← j ← x ← p
g ← i ← s ← q
c ← o ← w ← k
h ← n ← r ← l
```

Comment: thanks @PavelAnossov can u tell me why are u looping only for n+1/2

Comment: I'm looping over one corner and swapping with the three other corners.

Comment: range((n + 1) / 2) - in this command the inside part is computed just once and whole loop runs on the created list right?

Comment: Yes. You can avoid creating a list altogether if you use `xrange` instead of `range`. Note: this code is for python 2. In python 3, `range` works like `xrange` and you have to use `//` instead of `/` for integer division.

Comment: can u pls tell me how u are looping over one corner with range((n + 1) / 2) - I am unable to visualise

Comment: thank you so much ... you dont know how much i was struggling to understand this :) can you also tell me how u arrived at this solution.. is it out of experience or is there something important to look out for in such problem (ps : i tried generalizing and writing my own function but couldnt)

Comment: I just read the answers you linked and rewrote the top one in more concise python. I wouldn't trust myself with implementing a matrix operation from scratch, there's rarely a need to. Plenty of people already thought about it and tested it, why waste their effort? :)