# Logical Error in rotating a NxN matrix by 90 degree in place

Tags: java, matrix, logic

I am using the below code to rotate a NxN matrix by 90 degrees to the left. But it has some logical error. Most of the elements have rotated, but some haven't still. Please help me correct the code.

```
int n = 4, x = 1, i, j, temp;
int a[][] = new int[n][n];

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        a[i][j] = x++;
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
    for (j = n - 1; j >= n / 2; j--) {

        temp = a[i][j];
        a[i][j] = a[n - 1 - i][j];
        a[n - 1 - i][j] = a[j][i];
        a[j][i] = a[i][n - 1 - j];
        a[i][n - 1 - j] = temp;
    }
}


for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "rotating by 90"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your program a little bit and now it works. I have provided codes for rotating the matrix by 90 degrees on left as well as right. Have a look.

```
for (i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
    for (j = i; j < n - 1 - i; j++) {
        //Rotating left by 90 degrees
        temp = a[i][j];
        a[i][j] = a[j][n - 1 - i];
        a[j][n - 1 - i] = a[n - 1 - i][n - 1 - j];
        a[n - 1 - i][n - 1 - j] = a[n - 1 - j][i];
        a[n - 1 - j][i] = temp;

        /*
        //Rotating right by 90 degrees
        temp = a[i][j];
        a[i][j] = a[n - 1 - j][i];
        a[n - 1 - j][i] = a[n - 1 - i][n - 1 - j];
        a[n - 1 - i][n - 1 - j] = a[j][n - 1 - i];
        a[j][n - 1 - i] = temp;
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This was what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you were trying to use the code from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488691/how-to-rotate-a-matrix-90-degrees-without-using-any-extra-space), but it didn't work.  I transcripted the answer verbatim (AFAIK) into Java.  I don't know what direction you want to rotate but maybe this will help you.

```
int n = 4;
int a[][] = new int[n][n];
int f = Math.floor((double)n/2);
int c = Math.ceil((double)n/2);

for (int x=0; x < f; ++x) {
    for (int y=0; y < c; ++y) {
        int temp = a[x,y];
        a[x, y] = a[y, n-1-x];
        a[y, n-1-x] = a[n-1-x, n-1-y];
        a[n-1-x, n-1-y] = a[n-1-y, x];
        a[n-1-y, x] = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variant for rotating 90 degrees by left, this solution is only dealing with int. It also cares for odd dimension values.

```
int dim = 5;
int a[][] = new int[dim][dim];
int floor = dim / 2;
int ceil = (dim + 1) / 2;

for (int row = 0; row < floor; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < ceil; col++) {
        int oppRow = dim - row - 1;
        int oppCol = dim - col - 1;
        int temp = a[row][col];
        a[row][col] = a[col][oppRow];
        a[col][oppRow] = a[oppRow][oppCol];
        a[oppRow][oppCol] = a[oppCol][row];
        a[oppCol][row] = temp;
    }
}
```