# Rotate M*N Matrix (90 degrees)

Tags: c#, algorithm, matrix, rotation

How can I rotate matrix

```
|3 4 5 6 8|
|5 4 3 2 6|
|3 3 7 8 9|
```

to

```
|8 6 9|            
|6 2 8|
|5 3 7|
|4 4 3|
|3 5 3|
```

Because all algorithms I've seen was for N*N matrix.

Comment: Thats easy... think about which index goes where, and apply. Since you apparently don't care about speed too much, this is really simple.

Comment: What does your data structure look like?

Comment: No one of algorithms I tried don't helps...I tried a lot

Comment: Those link "How do you rotate a two dimensional array?" is for square matrix! I have non-square! This algorithm in not working!

Comment: I answered it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43694906/3221630

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If your matrix is represented by an array `matrix[i, j]`, where the `i` are the rows and the `j` are the columns, then implement the following method:

```
static int[,] RotateMatrixCounterClockwise(int[,] oldMatrix)
{
    int[,] newMatrix = new int[oldMatrix.GetLength(1), oldMatrix.GetLength(0)];
    int newColumn, newRow = 0;
    for (int oldColumn = oldMatrix.GetLength(1) - 1; oldColumn >= 0; oldColumn--)
    {
        newColumn = 0;
        for (int oldRow = 0; oldRow < oldMatrix.GetLength(0); oldRow++)
        {
            newMatrix[newRow, newColumn] = oldMatrix[oldRow, oldColumn];
            newColumn++;
        }
        newRow++;
    }
    return newMatrix;
}
```

This works for matrices of all sizes.

**Edit**: If this operation is too expensive, then one could try changing the way one *reads* the matrix instead of changing the matrix *itself*. For example, if I am displaying the matrix as follows:

```
for (int row = 0; row < matrix.GetLength(0); row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < matrix.GetLength(1); col++)
    {
        Console.Write(matrix[row, col] + " ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

then I could represent a 90-degree counterclockwise rotation by changing the way I read the matrix:

```
for (int col = matrix.GetLength(1) - 1; col >= 0; col--)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        Console.Write(matrix[row, col] + " ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

This access pattern could be abstracted in a class, too.

Comment: This doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Is there any more efficient way to do such a thing?  Take for example the need to swap width for height during realtime (large) image manipulation.

Comment: @SteveCarter, I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to create another matrix, which has the dimensions N * M (if the original has M * N) and then use nested loops to copy values from one matrix to another...
Just mind the correct index usage.