# How to rotate a 2D array at non integral angle

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, vb.net, rotation

**Application:**

I am doing analysis of a laser beam which is imaged on an IR camera. The goal is the have a real-time measurement, or at least as fast as the camera, which refreshes about once every 125 ms.

[image: Beam detail]

The algorithm will sum the intensities between the yellow dashed lines, and outside of them, then find the ratio. The yellow dashed lines are rotated at the same angle as the beam's angle. The beam's angle is *almost never a multiple of 45 degrees*.

I receive the beam in the form of a 2D array from the camera. It is represented by a 32-bit Integer array of size 1360 x 1024. I want to rotate the array so the yellow dashed lines are perpendicular to the bounds of the array, which would make the summing algorithm simpler.

**What I've tried:**

I looked into `System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix.Rotate()`, as has been suggested in answers to similar questions. However, this applies to `Graphics` objects. Using that method I have rotated images. But I haven't found a way to perform a similar operation on a 2D array.

**Edit**

The algorithm actually finds `w` such that the lines encompass `n%` of the beam's energy. I have tried traversing the entire array without rotation and checking the boundaries using the lines (y = mx + b), however, since I do many iterations of this operation, it is too costly. Again, I have 1.4 million values in the entire image.

The reason I want to rotate is to calculate sums of each row of the rotated array (resulting in a beam profile), then find the narrowest `w` which produces `n%` enclosed energy.

The following image shows the rotated beam, the profile (1D array of sums, in red), and the width (blue).

[image: Rotated beam with profile and width]

Comment: Looks like a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034805/rotate-mn-matrix-90-degrees

Comment: @MailmanOdd - that's for a 90-degree rotation.  The question is asking for an arbitrary rotation transform.

Comment: Looks like I should have read the question better :)

Comment: You've tagged VB.NET and C# - which are you using?

Comment: You can always create graphics object from array... bitmap isnt anything else then 2D array. see:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.unlockbits(v=vs.110).aspx
In similar manner it should be possible to lock array if in correct format.

Comment: Is the data in layered single array of `int[]` or a 2D array of `int[,]`. You kind of have to show your data structures to get an answer.

Comment: Note that a rotation will result in non-rectangular data, and so you have to choose if you want to trim the results, or enlarge the area (which affects your ratio).

Comment: Is the dashed line separation given in pixels or in physical dimensions. If so, what are the real dimensions of the image?

Comment: @J... Either C# or VB.net would be fine

Comment: @ja72 It is an `int[,]`. I would use the same sized resulting array, and fill in the other points with 0 - the intensities quickly go to 0 anyway when moving away from the beam. The dashed line is in pixels in my algorithm, but I would convert to um. A realistic width is around 600 um. I understand I would need to use cosines to translate to actual width after rotating. Thanks

Comment: @wondra My data is of type Int32. The image you see is just a visual representation in 24-bit-per-pixel format, and actually using only 8 colors :)

Comment: If you want % of total inensity then the ratio is wrong. You need `sum(inside)/all` instead of `sum(inside)/sum(outside)`.

Comment: So what when two image pixels fall on the same rotated pixel because of aliasing, do you add the intensities, or average?

Comment: @ja72 I would average - you could have up to 5 pixels on the same rotated pixel i guess...

Comment: With the additional information, am I to understand that you wish to perform a minimization algorithm on *each* frame (every 125ms?) in real time?  That you want to determine the angle of the central axis that bisects the beam profile along its minimum width?  If yes, this could be a rather difficult problem.  I might suggest that something like Matlab would be by far the more suitable tool to use - it has CUDA libraries that can accelerate these kinds of matrix operations many hundreds of times over what you will be able to achieve in C#.

Comment: @J... The angle is already found and returned by the camera's firmware. What we're trying to find is the minimum width of two lines which contain n% of the beam's energy. The two lines are parallel with the beam's angle. We do have this algorithm in Matlab but since we are a small team (2.5 devs, the 0.5 person wrote the Matlab) we want to reduce the number of languages we use for maintainability. The Matlab algorithm is not directly convertible to .NET. Also if I could rotate the array, the algorithm could be parallelized. We're using VB.NET primarily but don't mind using C# libraries.

Comment: @DanVerdolino Ok, so you will already know the angle.  That makes it much easier.

Comment: Forgotten about this question?

Comment: No. But I decided not to rotate. Instead I am checking each point for inclusion within parallel lines found with some trig... pretty close to njenson's solution, so I've accepted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an interesting idea that may be a bit different than what you have above. Here is the algorithm:

- Create two variables for the sums: `betweenSum` and `outsideSum`
- Get the equation for both lines (`y = mx+b`)

  - m = tan((-1)theta) where theta is the angle of the line w/ x axis. b = y intercept
- Go through each entry in the 2D array.

  - if the entry's x and y coordinates put in between both equations, then add the intensity to the betweenSum.
  - else add intensity to the outsideSum.

This approach is quite a bit different, and I'm not sure if this is something that is practical for your project. Just offering an approach that may help avoid doing rotation (and maybe any extra overhead).

Comment: I agree that this is more efficient. It is better to get the algorithm right, rather that rotating the data.

Comment: The algorithm is a bit more complicated than I shared in the question. The main goal is actually to find the width which encompasses n% of the energy. I have explored the approach in your answer and there are a lot of extra calculations in that approach.

Comment: It isn't that hard, once you have the math down. A Bisection method should be in order once you get the ratio of each width.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have the conversion from pixel to physical coordinates correct (and back). Then what you want is this:

```
public struct ImageData
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Intensity map
    /// </summary>
    int[,] intensities;
    /// <summary>
    /// Pixel dimensios of image like 1360 × 1024
    /// </summary>
    Size pixel_size;

    /// <summary>
    /// Physical dimensions like 300μ × 260μ
    /// </summary>
    SizeF actual_size;

    /// <summary>
    /// Transforms pixel coordinates to actual dimensions. Assumes center of image is (0,0)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pixel">The pixel coordinates (integer i,j)</param>
    /// <rereturns>The physical coordinates (float x,y)</rereturns>
    public PointF PixelToPoint(Point pixel)
    {
        return new PointF(
            actual_size.Width*((float)pixel.X/(pixel_size.Width-1)-0.5f),
            actual_size.Height*((float)pixel.Y/(pixel_size.Height-1)-0.5f));
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Transforms actual dimensions to pixels. Assumes center of image is (0,0)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="point">The point coordines (float x,y)</param>
    /// <returns>The pixel coordinates (integer i,j)</returns>
    public Point PointToPixel(PointF point)
    {
        return new Point(
            (int)((pixel_size.Width-1)*(point.X/actual_size.Width+0.5f)),
            (int)((pixel_size.Height-1)*(point.Y/actual_size.Height+0.5f)));
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the ratio of intensities included inside the strip (yellow lines). 
    /// Assume beam is located at the center.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="strip_width">The strip width in physical dimensions</param>
    /// <param name="strip_angle">The strip angle in degrees</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public float GetRatio(float strip_width, float strip_angle)
    {
        // Convert degrees to radians
        strip_angle*=(float)(Math.PI/180);
        // Cache sin() and cos()
        float cos=(float)Math.Cos(strip_angle), sin=(float)Math.Sin(strip_angle);
        //line through (xc,yc) with angle ψ is  (y-yc)*COS(ψ)-(x-xc)*SIN(ψ)=0
        //to offset the line by amount d, by add/subtract d from the equation above
        float inside=0, all=0;
        for(int i=0; i<pixel_size.Width; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<pixel_size.Height; j++)
            {
                Point pixel=new Point(i, j);
                //find distance to strip center line
                PointF point=PixelToPoint(pixel);
                float t=-sin*point.X+cos*pixel.Y;
                if(Math.Abs(t)<=strip_width/2)
                {
                    inside+=intensities[i, j];
                }
                all += intensities[i,j];
            }
        }
        return inside/all;
    }
    public void RotateIntesities(float angle)
    {
        // Convert degrees to radians
        angle*=(float)(Math.PI/180);
        // Cache sin() and cos()
        float cos=(float)Math.Cos(angle), sin=(float)Math.Sin(angle);
        int[,] result=new int[pixel_size.Width, pixel_size.Height];
        for(int i=0; i<pixel_size.Width; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<pixel_size.Height; j++)
            {
                Point pixel=new Point(i, j);
                PointF point=PixelToPoint(pixel);
                PointF point2=new PointF(
                    point.X*cos-point.Y*sin,
                    pixel.X*sin+point.Y*cos);
                Point pixel2=PointToPixel(point2);
                if(pixel2.X>=0&&pixel2.X<pixel_size.Width
                    &&pixel2.Y>=0&&pixel2.Y<pixel_size.Height)
                {
                    result[pixel2.X, pixel2.Y]+=intensities[i, j];
                }
            }
        }

        intensities=result;
    }
}
```

make sure the intesities are all positive (to avoid possible 1/0 condition). The strip center line is assumed to pass through center of beam.

Comment: I have added a rotate method, use at your own risk.

Comment: It will be some time until I can test this on a real beam. Thanks very much for the thorough answer.

Comment: At first glance, this is similar to a solution I came up with before. For one, the nested for-loop in `GetRatio` is executed once for each iteration of the search - yeah binary search so log(n), worst case 11 times. Also, this limits me to equidistant lines from the center - which won't necessarily solve for the smallest (best) width which yields `n%`. The reason I wanted to rotate was to come up with those sums which only need to be calculated once - which provides for a much faster search. You put the rotation, I will try both methods. Thank you again

Comment: The rotation skews the matrix (I believe to make every angle's data to fit into the matrix).

Comment: Again, I advise against rotating and dealing with the statistics using oblique strips.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to use the drawing transforms to rotate an `int[,]`.  The demo code below needs a new forms application with

- timer1 (Enabled, ~100ms)
- pictureBox1 (1360x1024, hook up paint handler)

This outputs the rotated data to `rotArr` and completes the operation in ~40ms (on my 4 year-old laptop).  Compiling for x86 seems to be faster here.  It may be just quick enough if you can manage the rest efficiently and have a reasonably new system to work with.  To get better speeds than this you can override the default interpolation mode using :

```
 g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
```

this reduces the quality of the rotated image but it can be faster.  A low interpolation quality may add uncertainty to your data - you'll have to test this.  Another flag you can test is

```
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
```

This adds time to the calculation (not much for me, but your mileage may vary), but may improve the fidelity of the rotated image (reduce artifact errors introduced by the transform).

This has to be C# - you said you'd prefer VB but you have to set "Allow unsafe code" in your project compile options for this work and VB does not support unsafe code.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int[,] imgArr = new int[1360, 1024];  //the 2D source from the camera
        private int[,] rotArr = new int[1360, 1024];  //the rotated output
        private float angle = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Make an RGB stripe for testing
            for (int i = 0; i < 1360; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 1024; j++)
                {
                    if (j < 333)
                    {
                        imgArr[i, j] = -65536; //0xFFFF0000 - red
                    }
                    else if (j < 666)
                    {
                        imgArr[i, j] = -16711936; //0xFF00FF00 - green
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        imgArr[i, j] = -16776961; //0xFF0000FF - blue
                    }                       
                }
            }          

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap drawImg;
            // Copy array to a bitmap - fast!
            unsafe
            {
                fixed (int* intPtr = &imgArr[0, 0])
                {
                    //swap width and height due to [,] row layout
                    drawImg = new Bitmap(1024, 1360, 4096,
                                  PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb, 
                                  new IntPtr(intPtr));                        
                }
            }

            // transform 
            GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
            gp.AddPolygon(new Point[]{new Point(0,0), 
                          new Point(drawImg.Width,0), 
                          new Point(0,drawImg.Height)});
            Matrix m = new Matrix();
            m.RotateAt(angle, new PointF((float)drawImg.Width/2, (float)drawImg.Height/2)); 
            gp.Transform(m);
            PointF[] pts = gp.PathPoints;

            //draw rotated image
            Bitmap rotImg = new Bitmap(1024, 1360);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rotImg);

            // for speed...default is Bilinear
            //g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;

            // may improve accuracy - default is no AntiAliasing
            // slows calculation
            // g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            g.DrawImage(drawImg, pts);

            //copy array data out 
            BitmapData bData = rotImg.LockBits(
                                        new Rectangle(new Point(), rotImg.Size),
                                        ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                                        PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            int byteCount = bData.Stride * (rotImg.Height);
            int[] flatArr = new int[byteCount / 4];
            //Do this in two steps - first to a flat array, then 
            //block copy to the [,] array
            Marshal.Copy(bData.Scan0, flatArr, 0, byteCount / 4);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(flatArr, 0, rotArr, 0, byteCount);

            // unlock the bitmap!!
            rotImg.UnlockBits(bData); 

            // for show... draw the rotated image to the picturebox
            // have to rotate 90deg due to [,] row layout
            rotImg.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(rotImg, new Point(0, 0));

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // increment angle and paint
            angle += 1.0f;
            if (angle > 360.0f) { angle = 0; }
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }

    }
 }
```

Comment: Note that this fully preserves the actual `Int32` values in the original array - they are temporarily pushed into a `Bitmap` and are interpreted there as 32-bpp ARGB values, but their fundamental value is not altered by the transformation .